# Diferença de performance na criação de FK MySQL

Tags: mysql, desempenho

Alguém sabe dizer se existe diferença de performance do banco caso eu crie as FK's antes dos outros campos na tabela ou vice-versa?

Ouvi comentários de que o ideal é deixar sempre as FK's como primeiras colunas da tabela, mas não encontrei nenhum artigo sobre.

Comment: Para deixar claro. Você está perguntando se a ordem dos campos no `create table` possui algum influência na *performance*, é isso? Trocando em miúdos, se ter uma campo como `FK` na segunda posição do `create table` é melhor do que ter o mesmo campo como `FK` na quinta posição (considerando os mesmos índices e todos os outros fatores iguais)?

Comment: Se for isso, encontrei [essa pergunta na SOE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894522/is-there-any-reason-to-worry-about-the-column-order-in-a-table) com respostas que sugerem que campos de tamanho variável (estilo `VARCHAR`) no meio da tabela podem impactar a *performance* na hora de recuperar os dados. A Resposta aceita sugere que a PK e FKs sejam os primeiros campos da tabela. Pessoalmente acho o tópico controverso quando você têm índices e *engines* inteligentes fazendo todo tipo de otimização. Mas sempre tento colocar os campos das `PKs` e `FKS` primeiro (se tornou uma convenção minha).

Comment: Essa era minha dúvida , realmente faz sentido. Coloque como resposta para que eu possa marcar como respondida. @AnthonyAccioly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme comentários, eu não possuo conhecimento de causa sobre o assunto, e nunca tomei tempo para mensurar *performance* investigando esse tipo de detalhe. Porém, a pergunta [*"Is there any reason to worry about the column order in a table?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894522/is-there-any-reason-to-worry-about-the-column-order-in-a-table) no SOE possui respostas que levam a crer que a ordem das colunas pode impactar a *performance* da recuperação de dados em alguns SGBDs, incluindo o MySQL.

A justificativa para isso, conforme os defensores dessa teoria, é que colunas de tamanho variável (e.g. `VARCHAR`) podem dificultar a recuperação de informações em colunas posteriores, uma vez que o MySQL (como alguns outros SGBDs) precisa percorrer as colunas no registro para descobrir o *offset* até a coluna pesquisada. Conforme [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/894552/664577) o impacto pode chegar a **17%** em uma tabela do MySQL com 20 colunas.

Por outro lado eu sempre tomo esse tipo de afirmação com um pouco de cautela. Além de SGDBs fazerem todo tipo de otimização no armazenamento e consulta de dados, eles estão em constante evolução, de forma que esse impacto pode não ser tão significativo. Em termos de *performance* eu acredito que reordenar colunas é no mínimo uma otimização precoce. Me preocupo bem mais com índices, planos de execução, *locks*, etc.

Dito isso, sempre adotei uma convenção que vai de encontro às melhores práticas sugeridas nas respostas. Procuro posicionar *Primary Keys* primeiro, *Foreign Keys* na sequência e então as demais colunas. Faço isso por questões de organização, mas se isso vem com um bônus de performance melhor ainda :).

A [resposta escolhida](https://stackoverflow.com/a/894545/664577) para a pergunta mencionada acima vai ainda mais longe sugerindo a seguinte ordem:

- Colunas da *primary key* primeiro
- Colunas de *foreign keys* na sequência
- Então colunas frequentemente buscadas
- Depois colunas frequentemente atualizadas
- Colunas *nullable* por último
- Colunas *nullable* menos utilizadas depois de colunas *nullable* frequentemente utilizadas